# Direct/ Inverse limits in category of (commutative) rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, limits-colimits

I have no idea if this is trivial or not, though I've been searching on internet quite a bit and still seems to be pretty vague in my head and didn't get a real answer.

In a module category over a ring $R$, we know that no matter what our direct/inverse system is, we can form its associated direct/inverse limit, which turns out to have an explicit description more or less given in any standard textbook of abstract algebra nowadays. However, I haven't figured out if the above is still true in case of (commutative) rings (perhaps an answer in the non-commutative setting if does exist would be appreciated too). Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commutative and non-commutative rings are models of a [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) so the categories of them are complete and cocomplete (i.e. have all limits [inverse limits] and colimits [direct limits]).  Indeed, most things you think of as categories of "algebraic" structures are categories of models of a Lawvere theory and thus are complete and cocomplete. There are some exceptions, e.g. fields and integral domains are not models of a Lawvere theory. (To be more precise, the *category* of fields is not a category of models of a Lawvere theory. Obviously, fields are rings and so are models of the Lawvere theory of rings.)

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you know any reference that deals with direct/inverse limits of rings and proves their existence?

Comment: I'd assume any categorical approach to abstract algebra would handle this. For example, it looks like Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0" does. Personally, though, I find the basics of algebraic theories are rather accessible. Proving that categories of models of an algebraic theory have all limits and sifted colimits and that they are calculated pointwise is very easy. It's a bit harder to show all colimits exist, but this reduces to showing finite coproducts exist. The fully general proof of cocompleteness is only 32 pages into [this](http://www.iti.cs.tu-bs.de/~adamek/algebraic_theories.pdf).